# Finding max values in columns using dplyr and return element from different column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, max

Assuming the below dataframe:

`df<-data.frame(a=c("red", "blue", "yellow", "orange"), b=c(1,4,5,7), c=c(2,7,4,1), d=c(4,3,8,1))`

Using `dplyr`, I would like to get the `a` element corresponding to each max and min in columns `b,c` and `d`:

For max, this would return `orange, blue and yellow`

I was able to get the index of the `max` value but couldn't get the value from column `a`:

`df %>% summarise(across(-c(1), ~which.max(.x)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `slice_max` after reshaping to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-a) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    slice_max(value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
#  a      name  value
#  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
#1 orange b         7
#2 blue   c         7
#3 yellow d         8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Reshape data to long and then group by the `name` variable which contains the columns. After that filter to get the maximum values and identify the observations in `a` variable. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% pivot_longer(-a) %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(value==max(value))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  a      name  value
  <fct>  <chr> <dbl>
1 blue   c         7
2 yellow d         8
3 orange b         7
```